# C# combobox selected item changing (from option clicked to bottom option)

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, google-sheets-api

When I select an option or change the selectedindex in the combobox, it displays as the bottom item before switching to the selected item.

Here is a video of the problem: https://imgur.com/gallery/5CTuSjI

I am fairly new to c#, so I apologize if my code isn't optimized / neat.

Code has some sensitive items, such as API keys and security info, so some will be missing.

Form1.cs

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Sheets.v4;
using Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.Data;
```

```cs
namespace Yugioh_Program
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // Events

        private void Label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

On load function (sets values of the combobox from spreadsheet)

```cs
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] _scopes = { SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheets };
            string _applicationName = "My Application Name from Google API Project ";
            string _spreadsheetId = "CONFIDENTIAL";
            string sheet = "ALL";

            SheetsService service;
            GoogleCredential credential;

            using (var stream = new FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream)
                    .CreateScoped(_scopes);
            }

            service = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = _applicationName,
            });

            List<List<string>> searchedCards = new List<List<string>>();

            var range = $"{sheet}!B2:G";
            var request = service.Spreadsheets.Values.Get(_spreadsheetId, range);

            var response = request.Execute();
            var values = response.Values;
            if (values != null && values.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var row in values)
                {
                    searchedCards.Add(new List<string> { row[0].ToString(), row[1].ToString(), row[2].ToString(), row[3].ToString(), row[4].ToString(), row[5].ToString() });
                }

            }

            Cards item = new Cards();

            List<string> addedCards = new List<string>();
            List<string> addedCardsNoDupe = new List<string>();

            foreach (List<string> subList in searchedCards)
            {
                addedCards.Add(subList[0]);
                addedCardsNoDupe = addedCards.Distinct().ToList();
            }
            foreach (string addedCard in addedCardsNoDupe)
            {
                item.Text = addedCard;
                item.Value = addedCard;
                NameSearch.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }
```

SelectedIndexChanged (when the contents of above combobox are changed, pulls values from spreadsheet, filters them using the option selected in above combobox and adds them to the list.

```cs
        private void NameSearch_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            // API call
            string[] _scopes = { SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheets };
            string _applicationName = "My Application Name from Google API Project ";
            string _spreadsheetId = "CONFIDENTIAL";
            string sheet = "ALL";

            SheetsService service;
            GoogleCredential credential;

            using (var stream = new FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream)
                    .CreateScoped(_scopes);
            }

            service = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = _applicationName,
            });

            List<List<string>> searchedCards = new List<List<string>>();
            List<List<string>> searchedSets = new List<List<string>>();

            var range = $"{sheet}!B2:G";
            var request = service.Spreadsheets.Values.Get(_spreadsheetId, range);

            var response = request.Execute();
            var values = response.Values;
            if (values != null && values.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var row in values)
                {
                    searchedCards.Add(new List<string> { row[0].ToString(), row[1].ToString(), row[2].ToString(), row[3].ToString(), row[4].ToString(), row[5].ToString() });
                }
                foreach (List<string> subList in searchedCards)
                {
                    //   name / set / rarity / edition / quantity / row number
                    searchedSets.Add(new List<string> { subList[0].ToString(), subList[1].ToString(), subList[2].ToString(), subList[3].ToString(), subList[4].ToString(), subList[5].ToString() });
                }
            }

            string selectedCard = NameSearch.Text.ToString();
            label1.Text = selectedCard;
            SetSearch.Items.Clear();

            Cards item = new Cards();

            foreach (List<string> subSet in searchedSets)
            {
                if (selectedCard == subSet[0])
                {
                    string addedText = subSet[0] + " | " + subSet[1] + " | " + subSet[2] + " | " + subSet[3];

                    item.Text = addedText;
                    item.Value = 0;

                    SetSearch.Items.Add(item);

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When i select "Dark magician" from the first combobox, the expected result is that selectedCard will = "dark magician", and the second combobox will be filtered by it.

Instead, what is happening is the last list item in the first combobox ("stardust dragon") is being selected, before the 1st combobox displays the selected option, and selectedCard = "stardust dragon" instead of the intended selected item.

New-ish to asking for code help, so if you need any more info / context etc please ask :)

Comment: You probably should use the `NameSearch.SelectedItem` or `NameSearch.SelectedValue`, typecast it to `Cards` instead of the Text property of the combobox, which might not be updated before the `SelectedIndexChanged` is fired.

Comment: One thing I noticed is that addedCardsNoDupe = addedCards.Distinct().ToList(); should probably be moved outside the foreach loop, otherwise you could end up with duplicates.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Have tried .SelectedItem with no change, and .SelectedValue gave me an error:
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Answer (score 0):

Add a member-level boolean flag to the form that indicates that the form is loading. In the **NameSearch_SelectedIndexChanged** event handler, check if the form is loading; if does just exit the handler; otherwise, continue.

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    boolean _formLoading;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _formLoading = true;
        ...
        ...
        ...
        _formLoading = false;
    }

    private void NameSearch_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_formLoading) return;
        ...
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Added suggested code, no change in response from the program.
I will try to record a video and add it to my question, as it is a bit tricky to describe.